# Disconnection between action dispatch and reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

What seems to be an issue is when `this.state` is called in `handleOnSubmit`, it does return the desired input.

However, once `this.state` is used as an argument in `this.props.addPhone(this.state)`, it returns `{type: "CREATE_PHONE", phone: undefined}`.

The code I belive is relevant to my question, starting from an action:

`addPhone` action:

```
export const addPhone = phone => {
  return {
    type: 'CREATE_PHONE',
    phone
  }
}
```

Phone Reducer(action is `undefined` here):

```
const phoneReducer = (state = {phones: [], loading: false}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_PHONE':
            
            const phone = {
                id: uuid(),
                make: action.make,
                model: action.model,
                price: action.price
            }
           return {...state, phones: [...state.phones, phone]}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default phoneReducer
```

And now, the Phone form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchPhones } from '../actions/phoneActions';
import { addPhone } from '../actions/phoneActions';
import PhoneList from './PhoneList';
class App extends Component {  
  state = {
    make: '',
    model: '',
    price: 0
  }

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    
  }

  handleOnSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.addPhone(this.state)
    this.setState({
      make: '',
      model: '',
      price: 0
    });
    
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchPhones()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>WELCOME TO OUR STORE</h2>
      <div>
        <h4>ADD A NEW PHONE</h4>
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit} >
          <input
            name="make"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.make}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange} /><br/>
            <input
            name="model"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.model}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange} /><br/>
            <input
            name="price"
            type="number"
            value={this.state.price}
            onChange={this.handleOnChange} /><br/><br/>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h4>CLICK HERE TO REMOVE PHONES</h4>
        <button> click here </button>
      </div>
      <div id="showPhones">
        
        <h4>SEE BELOW OUR PHONE OFFER</h4>
        
        <PhoneList phones={this.props.phones} loading={this.props.loading}/>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   
  return {
    phones: state.phones,
    loading: state.loading
  }
}
const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addPhone: () => dispatch(addPhone()),
    fetchPhones: () => dispatch(fetchPhones())
    
  }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(App)
```

What seems to be a mistake so `this.props.addPhone(this.state)` is returning: `{type: "CREATE_PHONE", phone: undefined}`?

I really do apologize if the question lacks professional code writing, but I am just a beginner in coding and on starckoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I dig in, i noticed,

```
addPhone: () => dispatch(addPhone()),
```

you need to at least pass the phone in this call, ex.

```
addPhone: phone => dispatch(addPhone(phone))
```

How does the dispatch know what to add :)

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I was stuck for two days, trying everything I could find. This solved it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: You are welcome, if it works, please accept the answer then :)